# Drupal Internal Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, drupal, web-config

I have a problem, i moved my drupal site, and i can see all my sites working. But sometimes when i editing them it comes "Internal Server Error". I think there is something wrong with my htaccess or my webconfig. As someone told me IIS doesn't use htaccess, but than it uses web.config.  The problem is it sometimes shows Error, sometimes not. So i think it has something to do with timeouts or something like that? Could that be?

I find out, what to do that the browser shows me the exact error:

It's this: "PHP Warning:  session_start(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in D:\Parallels\Plesk Panel\Vhosts\example.de\httpdocs\Intranet\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 1165
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in D:\Parallels\Plesk Panel\Vhosts\example.de\httpdocs\Intranet\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 1165"

Can you see something, where there is something wrong?

Comment: Look in your apache error logs.

Comment: It's a win 2008 r2 server. I checked the error log, i don't get them. What should be written in there?  2015-10-13 16:43:40 W3SVC6 S15438101 212.227.53.155 POST /intranet/node/493/edit - 80 - 79.230.198.39 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:41.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/41.0 SESS613c0ab0488ef3d23f6b5173cdd295fe=56hf8jl6b01vneq00epjphtop1;+has_js=1;+sticky_notes_visibility=visible http://www.example.de/intranet/node/493/edit www.examle.de 500 0 0 1737 6888 1875     This is one line, i think the 500, maybe means error 500 internal server error, or is this wrong?

Comment: So the system is win 2008 r2 server and i'm using IIS 7.5 and Plesk 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS doesn't use .htaccess files. It is a different beast altogether. It is unusual to run Drupal on Windows much less IIS, so you may not find much information. Luckily, Microsoft has their own Drupal distro that you can find at http://www.microsoft.com/web/drupal. You can use their distro as-is or as a template for configuring your own installation.

Comment: What about web.config file? Is Drupal using this? If IIS doesn't use htaccess, why there is the 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the 500 error because there really isn't enough information in the log entry you posted. Different parts of IIS fill the role of the .htaccess file. IIS has its own rewrite module, directory settings management, and 404 handler config. There is some info at http://thomas.bindzus.me/2010/06/23/setup-recess-framework-on-windows-7-using-iis-7/ about the possibility of importing rewrite rules from .htaccess into IIS, but I don't know enough about IIS to go into detail. Is there a reason you can't use something like WAMP/XAMPP to serve your site?

Comment: I will try to explain it. The system was running on an server. Now we moved. Actually its the same win 2008 r2 server, and also iis and plesk 12 this are the tools we used before. The site is an drupal site. In the error log of the drupal site is written: "Only variables should be passed by reference in D:\Parallels\Plesk Panel\Vhosts\atec-example.de\httpdocs\Intranet\sites\all\modules\webfm\webfm.module on line 2495." Maybe u know what this means and how to fix

Comment: That is a plesk error, not a Drupal error. I don't know anything about plesk so I can't be much help there.

Comment: Ok i will check stuff about Plesk, but why do you think it is an Plesk error? Maybe this will help me as well?